# triggering python functions with Pandas out put data

Tags: algorithm, function, dataframe, if-statement

I've been doing my best to get an if-else statement to be triggered by the last row of a pandas data frame,

if any1 can help me I'll appreciate

my code is

```
elif current_signal['move'] == 'Stay' and open_positions < 1:

    comparison_time = None
    Sell()
```

but i keep getting this error:

`raise ValueError( ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The wanted behavior is that if all of the values in this column are 'Stay' than enter the code section?

Comment: thanks for responding. no if the  column move in the last row is stay the i would like a predefined  function to be triggured, the dataframe refreshes with new data every 24hours

Comment: Your dataframe has only one row?

Comment: the data frame has multiple rows. i would like to isolate the data in the last row

"df[-1] "

my dataframe adds new data daily and so i would like my program to read the last row of data in the dataframe and trigger 1 of 3 functions every day depending on the new data in the last row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just incase any1 stumbles across this same problem, I managed to solve it finally.

I used the .sum() function to isolate the data I needed to trigger my function

heres a code snippet:

```
last_row = df.iloc[-1:]
signal = last_row['signal'].sum()
```

i don't know if this is the "RIGHT WAY TO DO IT" but it worked for me and maybe it might work for some1 else